# Decoding video stream chunks into PNG and timestamp

Tags: node.js

I am working on a frame-based intro detector and for that I need to compare every single frame of the video stream with preset png data, except I am stuck in trying to decode the chunks of the video stream: here's my simplified code:

```
http.request({
        host: myUrl.host,
        path: myUrl.pathname + myUrl.search,
}, async function(response) {
        /* response.headers output for reference:
        {
           'content-type': 'video/mp4',
           'content-length': '36906139',
           'accept-ranges': 'bytes'
        } */
        response.on("data", chunk => {
            //chunk is the encoded video data, i want to generate {pngBase64, timestamp}
        })
}).end();
```

Comment: mp4's are not images in series

Comment: do you maybe have an idea of a workaround in this case?

Comment: In short: ffmpeg.

Comment: i tried ffmpeg but i couldn't get it to do what i wanted